# linux copy symbolic link

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, symlink, cp

How do I copy a symbolic link from one directory to another?

```
ls -ls

file1.txt
file2.txt
files -> /mnt/iscsi-nfs-share/faulttracker-files
```

what I'm looking to do is copy files symbolic link into another directory?

```
cp files /var/copylinktohere/
```

the above results in
cp: omitting directory `files'

Comment: im only looking to copy the symlink not the actual contents of the directory

Comment: Did you have a look in the manual pages? If not, is `--no-dereference` what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks for this gave plus one.  I found all the options available a little confusing.

Comment: Belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Benjamin: Fair comment — no mention of C.  It is still on topic as it is about how to write shell programs (even if it is a one-liner). As such, it is fine on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use the `-d` option:

```
cp -d files /var/copylinktohere/
```

From `man cp`:

```
   -d     same as --no-dereference --preserve=link

   --no-dereference
          never follow symbolic links
```

Comment: does this work if the symbolic links are not relative? ie copying into a destination directory higher or lower than the source directory.

Comment: wouldn't it be quite the other way around?
Absolute symlinks work from every path, while relative symlinks can't work, if you change their path.
It's quite logic